# Split string with denominator not working

Tags: java, netbeans, split, assign

Quick question: I want to split an IP Address (eg. 192.168.0.1) using the period (.) as a delimiter. I can't seem to get it right. I tried running different scenarios to see if it's my brain dysfunctioning, but all seems to be well when putting spaces between the numbers instead of the periods. How do I do it successfully?

Here's a piece of the script that I'm using to run it.

```
String ipAddress = "10.0.0.2";
String[] split = ipAddress.split(".");
//It's supposed to split into four parts and each part needs to be assigned to a var
String Part1 = split[0];
String Part2 = split[1];
String Part3 = split[2];
String Part4 = split[3];
//Just to make sure that it worked...
System.out.println(Part1 + " " + Part2 + " " + Part3 + " " + Part4);
```

Before you question my knowledge, I'm learning myself new Java functions and sometimes I can't make it work.

Stay Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class that deals with IP address in Java, letting you obtain a proper representation without trying to parse the string yourself:

```
InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.2");
byte[] b = a.getAddress();
System.out.println(b[0]+" "+b[1]+" "+b[2]+" "+b[3]);
```

Comment: Both options (this answer and [user_CC's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15851375/1065197)) are covered in the answers in the possible duplicate question

Comment: Thanks! This works even better than the split() function!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] split = ipAddress.split("\\.");
```

The [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method takes a regular expression, not a string, and the **DOT** has a special meaning in regular expressions. So you need to escape it with double slash.

Or you can use [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] split = ipAddress.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  String parts[] = ipAddress.split("\\.")    //this is double back slash
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`String parts[] = ipAddress.split("\\.")`